# error using < and >

Tags: xcode, swift

hello I was making a simple guess the number game and suddenly I come up with
    Cannot invoke '<' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue UITextField!, @lvalue UInt32)
this is my whole script
    import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var guess: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var text: UILabel!
    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
        if guess > random {
            println(text = "your number was too high. Try again")
        }

        if guess < random {
            println(text = "your number was too low. Try again")
        }
    }

    var random = arc4random()%100
    ...
```

thanks

Comment: you can never compare a `UITextField` to an `UInt32`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the string contained in the `guess` text field into an integer, by using the `toInt()` method, which returns an optional though, in case the string is not convertible to a valid integer.

I would use optional binding to do the conversion and assign a valid value to a variable:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let guessInt = guess.text.toInt() {
        if guessInt > random {
            println("your number was too high. Try again")
        }

        if guessInt < random {
            println("your number was too low. Try again")
        }
    }
}
```

However that change alone doesn't work because `toInt` returns a `Int`, whereas `arc4random` returns a `UInt` - since swift doesn't have implicit conversion between data types, an explicit conversion to `Int` is needed:

```
var random = Int(arc4random()%100)
```

Answer (score 0):

you've defined "`guess`" as a UITextField, which is certainly not the same type as "`random`".

You need to tell the compiler how to convert that to an integer.

Something like:

```
let guessInteger = guess.text.toInt()
```

and then:

```
if guessInteger > random {
    println("\(guess.text) was too high. Try again")
}
```

Comment: I used your way and it gave me the same errors and 'ViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'guess'

Comment: Yeah, it should be "`toInt`" and not Objective-C's "`integerValue`"